# React Native: What the screen is displaying appears to be 1 step behind the buttons that change the display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Summary: count variables updates correctly but variables that update based on count variable are always 1 button press behind count.

I have two buttons that change the count variable to determine the width of 5 images that should slowly appear across the screen. I use the count variable to update grainFirst through grainFifth to display the image. The count variable updates correctly but it takes another press for the grainFirst variables to update. For example 1 press and count increases, grainFirst does not, 2 presses and count increases while grainFirst's value is what it should have been after the first press.

Here is the code I have. I started using React Native and javascript for the first time today so apologies if the formatting is not standard.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './assets/Style';

class Sample extends PureComponent{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      grainFirst: 0,
      grainSecond: 0,
      graindThird: 0,
      grainFourth: 0,
      grainFifth: 0,
      grainPortions: 11
    }
  }
  updateValues = () => {
    if(this.state.counter < 57){
      this.setState({grainFirst: this.state.counter})
    }else{
      this.setState({grainFirst: 58})
    }

    if(this.state.counter < 57){
      this.setState({grainSecond: 0})
    }else if(this.state.counter >= 57 * 2){
      this.setState({grainSecond: 57})
    }else{
      this.setState({grainSecond: this.state.counter % 57})
    }

    if(this.state.counter < 57 * 2){
      this.setState({grainThird: 0})
    }else if(this.state.counter >= 57 * 3){
      this.setState({grainThird: 57})
    }else{
      this.setState({grainThird: this.state.counter % 57})
    }

    if(this.state.counter < 57 * 3){
      this.setState({grainFourth: 0})
    }else if(this.state.counter >= 57 * 4){
      this.setState({grainFourth: 57})
    }else{
      this.setState({grainFourth: this.state.counter % 57})
    }

    if(this.state.counter < 57 * 4){
      this.setState({grainFifth: 0})
    }else if(this.state.counter >= 57 * 5){
      this.setState({grainFifth: 57})
    }else{
      this.setState({grainFifth: this.state.counter % 57})
    }
  }
  increaseCount = () => {
    if(this.state.counter < 285 - (285/this.state.grainPortions)){
      this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + (285/this.state.grainPortions)})
    }else{
      this.setState({counter: 285})
    }
    this.updateValues();
  }
  decreaseCount = () => {
    if(this.state.counter > (285/this.state.grainPortions)){
      this.setState({counter: this.state.counter - (285/this.state.grainPortions)})
    }else{
      this.setState({counter: 0})
    }
    this.updateValues();
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>this.decreaseCount()}>
        <Text>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.grains}>
          <Image source={require('./assets/Grains.jpeg')}
            style={{ width: this.state.grainFifth, height: 55}}
          />
          <Image source={require('./assets/Grains.jpeg')}
            style={{width: this.state.grainFourth, height: 55}}
          />
          <Image source={require('./assets/Grains.jpeg')}
            style={{width: this.state.grainThird, height: 55}}
          />
          <Image source={require('./assets/Grains.jpeg')}
            style={{width: this.state.grainSecond, height: 55}}
          />
          <Image source={require('./assets/Grains.jpeg')}
            style={{width: this.state.grainFirst, height: 55}}
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>this.increaseCount()}>
        <Text>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 5
        }}>{this.state.counter}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Sample
```

I have tried forcing the app to reload, changing how I increased the counter variable, and  created the updateValues function rather than doing it inside each of the count functions (but that was mostly to make the code more concise). I also moved around where I call updateValues(). From what I can tell the updateValues() does not get called until the button is pressed a second time but I am not sure. Any help or resources anyone can give will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue you're encountering is due to the asynchronous nature of `this.setState` in React.

Whenever you call `this.updateValues()` immediately after setting state in `increaseCount` and `decreaseCount`, there's no guarantee that the state has been updated yet as React batches state updates for performance reasons.

To ensure that `updateValues` is called after the state has been updated, you can provide a callback function to `this.setState`. Here's how you can update your `increaseCount` and `decreaseCount` functions:

```js
increaseCount = () => {
  if (this.state.counter < 285 - (285 / this.state.grainPortions)) {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + (285 / this.state.grainPortions) }, () => {
      this.updateValues(); // This callback will be executed after state is updated
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({ counter: 285 }, () => {
      this.updateValues(); // Callback for state update
    });
  }
}

decreaseCount = () => {
  if (this.state.counter > (285 / this.state.grainPortions)) {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - (285 / this.state.grainPortions) }, () => {
      this.updateValues(); // Callback for state update
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({ counter: 0 }, () => {
      this.updateValues(); // Callback for state update
    });
  }
}
```

By providing a callback function to `this.setState`, you ensure that `updateValues` is called after the state has been updated, which should resolve the issue of the UI appearing to be one step behind when you press the buttons.